# What journal should I submit a work in number theory to?

Tags: nt.number-theory, journals

I am just finishing up some work in number theory, but none of my professors could tell me where I should submit my work to (I am an undergrad). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not in number theory, but this is an impossible question for anyone to answer without seeing the paper itself. Do any of your professors know someone more knowledgeable whom you could consult?

Comment: A short answer is to try to find some papers similar to yours (in topic, style, importance, etc.) and submit your paper to one of the journals they appeared in.  It's hard to say more without knowing more about exactly what your research consists of, but I'm not sure mathoverflow is the right place for a detailed discussion.

Comment: A quick check would be to look where most of the papers you are using as a reference has been sent to. If there is a clear choice then try sending yours there. Of course, this doesn't cover every possibility!

Comment: See http://www.numbertheory.org/ntw/N6.html and http://www.numbertheory.org/ntw/N7.html

Comment: I still think it best that you try to show the paper to someone familiar with the topic covered in your paper but who is more knowledgeable and experienced and try to get guidance from that person.

Comment: By the way, I agree with Deane (my comment appeared after his but I started writing it before his; in hindsight his advice is better).

Comment: If you are all of bold, polite, and respectful, you can also try the following approach.  (This should supplement Deane Yang's suggestion, NOT replace it.)  Collect a list of email addresses to which you send a form letter.  The form letter includes a polite salutation, makes the request of the name of someone to review the result, includes a short summary of the result and methods used, provides a link to the writeup for those who want more as well as your contact info, ... (Continued) Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.23

Comment: ... states your intention of finding a journal to publish the result, and thanks the reader for their time.  It should be very brief and clear.  The list of recipients should include only those people that have a good shot of answering the request, primarily associate editors of journals or people who have written on or near the topic you have researched.  If these people get that you respect their time and input, some will engage with you, even if the answer is that your work is already well known.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.23

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start with googling for something like "journals specializing in number theory" to compile a list of some ~15 major number-theoretic journals. The next step is to cross out too ambitious journals, too "lightweight" journals, journals specializing in an area alien to yours etc; your professors should be able to help you with this. When you are left with some half-a-dozen of options, think of the papers you refer to: were they were published?  Remember, that you do not need to reduce your list to just one title: when you are left with some three journals or so, you can just pick one of them at random!